Understanding the precedence of the modulo operator
I'm using Zed Shaw's "Learn Python 3 The Hard Way"; the problem exercise is on page 16, and refers to counting eggs:
print(3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6)

The author says the answer is 6.75, and if I drop those numbers into a Python shell I can easily confirm that. I accept that using the PEMDAS principle the method would be to bracket up the numbers, so I calculate in the right order. But none of my various experiments have succeeded. How to go about this?

Modulo/Remainder operations usually have the same precedence as multiplication and division.

Mea culpa: I have since twigged that there is something of a 'trick' in the exercise, and that my lack of mathematical confidence led me to assume that I'd made an error in calculating "4 % 2" as "0". Once I'd got past that hurdle I could work with precedence AND the additional rule of working left-to-right thereafter. Thanks to tkausl for his help.
